# How can I make Bootstrap Select and Deselect buttons in accessible with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, accessibility, bootstrap-select

I am using the version of [bootstrap-select](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/) that has select all and deselect all buttons. When the multiselect dropdown is open, I need to be able to tab into those buttons. I tried adding this code to my js file, what am I doing wrong?

```
let bootstrapSelect = document.getElementsByClassName(bootstrap-select);
let bsSelectAll = document.getElementsByClassName(bs-select-all);

$(bootstrapSelect).on('click', function () {
  if((this).hasClass('open')) {
    $(bsSelectAll).addClass('focus-visible')
  }});
```

Comment: Pretty sure this is a timing issue, by the time your if statement is reached the "open" class won't have had time to be applied to the element. What happens when you do a setTimeout before the if statement, start with something silly like a second?

Comment: I think I figured it out, someone had set outline to none which disabled the accessibility tab in and arrows.

Comment: That doesn't disable accessibility. It just masks it. Yes, disabling outline is a bad practice.

Comment: Please provide and accept an answer or delete your question. Abandoned posts are ugly.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help!

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. Someone had set `outline` to `none` which masked the accessibility tab-in and arrows.